# How do I save a UILabel's properties in a NSMutableArray?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios7

For example,

```
-(void)drawHypnoticMessage:(NSString *)message{

....


UILabel messageLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];

messageLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
messageLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
messageLabel.text = message;

[messageLabel sizeToFit];

int width = (int)(self.view.bounds.size.width - messageLabel.bounds.size.width);

int x = arc4random() % width;

int height = (int)(self.view.bounds.size.height - messageLabel.bounds.size.height);

int y = arc4random() % height;

CGRect frame = messageLabel.frame;
frame.origin = CGPointMake(x,y);
messageLabel.frame = frame;

[self.view addSubview:messageLabel];

...}
```

I want to be able to add this label "messageLabel" to a NSMutable array like this:

```
NSMutableArray *thisArray;

[thisArray addObject:messageLabel];
```

and then access it later after STATE RESTORATION like this:

```
UILabel *thisLabel = [thisArray objectAtIndex:0];
[self.view addSubview: thisLabel];
```

For some reason, when I try to access the UILabel stored inside the NSMutableArray, the text in ---> thisLabel.text <--- shows up empty. In Addition, all the properties in the --->thisLabel<--- also shows up empty when I try to access it again after STATE RESTORATION.

such as:

--->thisLabel.textColor<---- shows up empty. 
--->thisLabel.frame    <---- shows up empty.

Can anybody help me solve this quirk? It's really frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to be able to add this label "messageLabel" to a NSMutable
> array like this:
>
> NSMutableArray *thisArray;
>
> ```
> [thisArray addObject:messageLabel];
> ```

#### Did you remember to first say

```
thisArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

Comment: reallocation of the NSMutableArray - does this happen at all?